# Can a $\phi$ meson decay into a pair of charged pions ($\pi^-$ and $\pi^+$)?

Tags: standard-model, strong-force, mesons, pions

I understand that $\phi^0 \to \pi^+ \pi^- \pi^0$ is OZI suppressed.

But how about $\phi^0 \to \pi^+ \pi^-$?

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phi_meson) doesn't list this decay path but $\phi^0 \to K^+ K^-$. Why? $\phi^0$ is a mixing of $u \bar u$, $d \bar d$, and $s \bar s$, so it seems okay to decay to a pair of charged pions as well.

[image]

Comment: You got it *spectacularly wrong* about the [φ composition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meson#Vector_mesons), I won't ask *how*.  This is the very particle and composition that actually *led* to the OZI rule.

Comment: @CosmasZachos, I thought it's a mixing because it's one of the three particles ($\omega$, $\rho^0$, $\phi$) in the centre of vector meson nonet. The wikipedia I mentioned above says that "The quark composition of the $\phi$ meson can be thought of as a mix between ss, uu, dd state, but it is very nearly a pure ss state." So do we just ignore the possible decay paths of uu or dd?

Comment: Yes, it is very nearly a pure ssbar state. That's the whole *point* of the OZI rule... that's how it was discovered. Ignore WP and go to a reputable text on ω-φ mixing, for crying out loud....

Comment: See https://pdg.lbl.gov for all decays

Comment: @CosmasZachos, thanks! Is there a textbook you’d like to recommend that talks about the mixing? I’m taking my first course in particle physics and can’t quite find some clear introductory texts about this

Comment: An older book by Perkins is quite good…

Comment: see end of this reference https://www.ippp.dur.ac.uk/~krauss/Lectures/QuarksLeptons/QCD/Quarkonium_0.html